# If each $\operatorname{Spec}(\iota_i) \circ f$ are flat, then $f$ is also flat ( $\iota_i : A/\mathfrak{p}_i \to \prod_{i=1}^n(A/\mathfrak{p}_i)$)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Theorem 14.32 and some question arises.

Let $A$ be a reduced local noetherian ring and $\mathfrak{p}_1, \cdots \mathfrak{p}_n$ be its minimal prime ideals.

Let $\iota_i : R_i:=A/\mathfrak{p}_i \to R:=\prod_{i=1}^n(A/\mathfrak{p}_i)$ be its canonical injections.
Let $f: X\to Y:=\operatorname{Spec}(\prod_{i=1}^n(A/\mathfrak{p}_i))$ be a morphism locally of finite type.

Then, if each $\operatorname{Spec}(\iota_i) \circ f$ are flat, then $f$ is also flat?

By the condition, we have that for each $x\in X$ and $i \in I:=\{1,2, \cdots n\}$,   $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p}_i), \iota_i^{-1}(f(x))}
= (A/\mathfrak{p}_i)_{\iota_i^{-1}(f(x))}$-flat module.

We have to show that for each $x\in X$, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is flat $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} = (\prod A/\mathfrak{p}_i)_{f(x)}$-module.

Can we prove this? If so, how?

To show that, I want to show that :

> Let $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(\prod_iA/\mathfrak{p}_i)$ be a prime ideal. Let $M$ be a
> $(\prod_iA/\mathfrak{p}_i)_{\mathfrak{p}})$-module.
> If we have that $M$ is flat $(A/\mathfrak{p}_i)_{\iota_i^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})}$-flat module for all $i \in I$, then $M$ is flat $(\prod_iA/\mathfrak{p}_i)_{\mathfrak{p}})$-module?

More generally, can we show that

> Let $\{R_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a finite set of (locally noetherian) rings. Let $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R:=\prod_i R_i)$ be a prime ideal. Let $\iota_i : R_i \to \prod_iR_i=:R$ be the canonical injections. Let $M$ be a $R_\mathfrak{p}$-module.
> Then if $M$ is flat $(R_i)_{\iota_i^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})}$ -flat module for all $i\in I$, then
> $M$ is flat $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module?

My one of attempts is using next Theorem ( Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra, Theorem 6.8 )

[image]

Let $\mathfrak{p} :=f(x)$. We have (local?) ring homomorphisms

$$ R_{i,\iota^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})} \xrightarrow{\iota_{i,\mathfrak{p}}} R_\mathfrak{p}=\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \xrightarrow{f^{\sharp}_x}  \mathcal{O}_{X,x} $$

( where $\iota_{i,\mathfrak{p}} : a/b \mapsto \iota_i(a)/\iota_i(b)$ ? )

By the theorem, we have

$$ \operatorname{Tor}_{1}^{R_{i,\iota^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})}}(\operatorname{Frac}(R_i/\iota^{-1}_i(\mathfrak{p})),\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) =0 $$

for all $i$.

Then can we deduce from this data that

$$ \operatorname{Tor}_{1}^{R_{\mathfrak{p}}}(\operatorname{Frac}(R/\mathfrak{p}),\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) =0 $$ ?

In our condition, base rings are different. (That makes me annoying)

My question originates from the next proof in Gortz's Algebraic Geometry ( Theorem 14.32) :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Why the underlined statement is true?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why would you underline a reference to corollary 14.30 (which is the stated justification for what you're trying to understand!) and then not include it in your post?

Comment: Because, I knew that the Corollary 14.30 was separate from "We can then check the flatness by checking it over each factor." You mean, we can deduce our goal with the help of the Corollary 14.30? Then how? I underline Corollary 14.30. Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: There are two steps here: reduce to the product, then note that you can check on each factor of the product. The latter is obvious: if a scheme $X$ is a disjoint union of schemes $X_i$, then $\mathcal{O}_{X_i,x} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ so one can check flatness component-by-component. If you understand 14.30, then this is the only thing to check, but your work suggests you have questions on more than just this step.

Comment: You said, "so one can check flatness component-by-component." I don't completely understand what it means exactly. Does it means that $\operatorname{Spec}(\iota_i) \circ f$ are flat $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is flat, as I asked in the question?

Comment: Let me expand my own argument. Note that $Y:= \operatorname{Spec}(\prod_{i=1}^{n}(A/\mathfrak{p_i}))=\coprod_{i=1}^{n}(\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p_i}
 ))$. Let $\psi : \operatorname{Spec}(\prod_{i=1}^{n}(A/\mathfrak{p_i})) \cong \coprod_{i=1}^{n}(\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p_i}))$ be the isomorphism.

 
  Fix $x\in X$. Then $\psi(f(x)) \in \coprod_{i=1}^{n}(\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p_i}))$. So there exists
   $i$ such that $\psi(f(x)) \in \operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p}_i)$. Then as you commented, $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \cong (A/\mathfrak{p_i})_{\psi(f(x))}$.

Comment: My question is, $\psi(f(x)) = \iota_i^{-1}(f(x))$, where $\iota_i : A/\mathfrak{p_i} \to \prod_{i=1}^{n}(A/\mathfrak{p_i})$ is the canonical injection?. If so, then if each $\operatorname{Spec}(\iota_i) \circ f$ is flat, then as I argued early in the question, we are done.

Comment: Am I following your intention well? Or is there any other direction consistent with your intentions (to check flatness?)

Comment: O.K.. If we can show that $\psi = \varphi_i \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\iota_i)$, where $\varphi_i : \operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p_i}) \hookrightarrow \coprod_{i=1}^{n}(\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{p_i}))$ is the inclusion, then we can show that $\psi(f(x)) = \iota_i^{-1}(f(x))$. And is it true?

Comment: If you have a scheme map $\coprod X_i \to Y$, then checking flatness of this is equivalent to checking flatness of each of the maps $X_i\to Y$ (this should be straightforward to show). I hope you can figure it out from here because I am not going to read all the stuff you just wrote - somehow you manage to make simple things very complicated and that is tiring for me. (Perhaps you would benefit from someone to talk about things with in real life - a fellow graduate student, a professor, an advisor, etc.)

Comment: O.K. Anyway thank you very much ! :)